# Bash For Loop skip numbers

Tags: python, bash

i want to create bash script.

that skip 1000 on each loop untill 2M,

i'm stuck here:

```
for i in {1..2000000} ; do

done;
```

for exmple:

the first loop:

```
offset=0
```

second loop:

```
offset=100
```

3rd loop

```
offset=2000
```

until 2M

i try few ways but with no success.

python will be welcome also

how can i do that?

Comment: _"i try few ways but with no success."_ - Please show those attempts then.

Comment: updated. i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Use while loop :

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 2000000 ] 
  do
    echo offset=$i
    i=$(($i+1000))
  done
```

Comment: I replace `$[...]` with POSIX `$((...))`. The square bracket version is so obsolete that `bash` doesn't even document it anymore; even when it was documented, it was marked as deprecated (and had been since the late 90s). I have no idea why it is still supported.

Comment: But the `while` loop, while more verbose than either `bash` extension, has the benefit of being POSIX-compliant, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the C-style `for` loop:

```
for ((i=0; i <= 2000000; i+=1000)); do
```

`bash` does support a brace expansion operator that lets you generate sequences with strides greater than one (support appears to have been added in 4.0, although there is no mention in the release notes):

```
for i in {0..200000..1000}
```

However, the C-style loop is preferable because it generates the values of `i` lazily, rather than creating the entire sequence in memory before starting the iteration. Unless you are generating absolutely enormous sequences, this will not usually be an issue, but you might notice a short delay while the sequence is generated.

Comment: you the best! thanks a lot. how did you find this? any more things in bash 4?